How do I defer the full definition of a type?
Assume I have the following subprogram declared in the specification.
package Waiter is
  type Time_Span is ????; -- Time_Span definition TBD...

  procedure Wait (Period : Time_Span);  
end Waiter;


The body package will be implemented by the platform. On platforms with a full runtime, Time_Span is already defined by Ada.Real_Time. On others with a more restricted runtime, it's not defined at all.
How do I define Time_Span such that both platforms can use the same specification?
tried to use null records and private types.

See also Data type of Time_Span and Time in Ada.

I'm afraid you can't. Provide package specification per platform also. There is a case when Time_Span is an access type to a platform specific type, but I guess it doesn't work here.

@MaximReznik, I can see why AdaDriverLibraries uses integers for duration.

Have you considered making a folder for platforms that don't support Ada.Real_Time (and others) and Make an Ada.Real_Time stub with just the things you need like Time_Span?  You can have gprbuild include that source folder with stubbed version for platforms that don't normally support it.  Then in your package you could just with Ada.Real_Time (and subtype Time_Span in it) and gprbuild can handle picking the right one based on the platform picked

Hmmm. Interesting but not quite sure I understand. The details of where and how Time_Span is defined are critical in getting it to work, otherwise you'll it will be either undefined or already defined. If possible an example?

you add an external variable to your gprbuild file (see: https://github.com/Blady-Com/gnoga/blob/master/settings.gpr ).  You can then use that variable in a case statement within gprbuild (see: https://github.com/Blady-Com/gnoga/blob/master/src/gnoga.gpr ).  The example above sets a different body based on the buld target, but you could also set a different Source_Dirs instead and put the extra spec in a specific folder chosen by that case statement.  Sorry I couldn't immediately find a good single example.   It's split between two

Added an answer as an example

I think Jeffery Carter had a better answer for you, but if you don't want to use that specific one, you can use gprbuild to selectively pick a default Ada package or a stub package based on an external variable.
The way you do this is by making your own package.  We'll call it Real_Time:
package Real_Time with Pure is

   type Time_Span is new Integer;  -- Use whatever type you want here

end Real_Time;

place it in a subfolder of your source folder, say target_1 (name however you want)
Then make another subfolder, say target_2 (again name however you want) and in it put another package named Real_Time (same name as before in target_1) but this time just have it rename Ada.Real_Time.  This will be for targets that support Ada.Real_Time.
with Ada.Real_Time;

package Real_Time renames Ada.Real_Time;

Then have your Waiter package use the Real_Time package in place of Ada.Real_Time:
with Real_Time;

package Waiter is
  subtype Time_Span is Real_Time.Time_Span; -- Time_Span definition TBD...

  procedure Wait (Period : Time_Span) is null;
end Waiter;

Now just setup your gpr file to select the one you want based on an external variable:
project Default is

   type Target_Kind is ("target1", "target2");
   Target_Selected : Target_Kind := external("TARGET_SRC", "target1");

   for Create_Missing_Dirs use "True";
   for Object_Dir  use "obj";
   for Exec_Dir    use "bin";
   for Main        use ("main.adb");
   for Languages   use ("ada");

   case Target_Selected is
      when "target1" => for Source_Dirs use ("src") & ("src/target_1");
      when "target2" => for Source_Dirs use ("src") & ("src/target_2");
   end case;

   -- put compiler switches and other things here

end Default;

Then when you build for target 1 use:
gprbuild -XTARGET_SRC=target1
and for target 2 use:
gprbuild -XTARGET_SRC=target2
You can pick a better name than TARGET_SRC and such.  This is just for example
Full example at:  https://github.com/jere-software/ada_examples/tree/master/gprbuild_split_source

You can do this with type extension and class-wide types:
private with Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders;

package Waiter is
   type Time_Span is private;

   function To_Span (Interval : in Duration) return Time_Span;
   -- Other functions to obtain a Time_Span

   procedure Wait (Period : Time_Span);
private -- Waiter
   type Root is abstract tagged null record;

   function Equal (Left : in Root'Class; Right : in Root'Class) return Boolean is
      (Left = Right);

   package Class_Holders is new Ada.Containers.Indefinite_Holders
      (Element_Type => Root'Class, "=" => Equal);
  
   type Time_Span is record
      Value : Class_Holders.Holder;
   end record;
end Waiter;

The package body then extends Root to create the actual type stored in the holder. For example, for an implementation using Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span:
with Ada.Real_Time;

package body Waiter is
   type Real_Span is new Root with record
      Value : Ada.Real_Time.Time_Span;
   end record;
   
   function To_Span (Interval : in Duration) return Time_Span is
      (Value =>
          Class_Holders.To_Holder
             (Real_Span'(Root with Value => Ada.Real_Time.To_Time_Span (Interval) ) ) );

   procedure Wait (Period : Time_Span) is
      -- Empty
   begin -- Wait
      delay Ada.Real_Time.To_Duration (Real_Span (Period.Value.Element).Value);
   end Wait;
end Waiter;

Since what is stored in a holder is Root'Class, you have to explicitly convert it to Real_Spanas in Wait. It's a bit of a pain, but it allows you to have a package that allows its clients to use a type declared in the package body.

This issue could be solved if private types can be defined in a separate body, which is in the spirit of private types. The point is to hide the implementation, correct?
